# How to save map data in a tilebased game

Tags: java, 2d, data-storage

I have a bit of a rookie question regarding storage of map data i a java game. I'm making a 2d tile-based game, where each tile has an id (1, 2, 3, 4 and so on...). I currently store the game data in a .txt file, where each number is seperated by a tab. Therefrom i read it via scanners .nextInt.

This method works fine, but it seems to give me a problem:

- Since the level file is just a normal .txt file it is easily edited by anyone. This means that the user could just change a few numbers in the file with any kind of text editor and thereby easily cheat.

How would this be avoided? Should i store the map data differently or should i use some form of encryption?

Comment: Dump the object to a file, zipped with password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this would be to store the data in a database, such as derby. Once the game has been exported as a jar file the casual player will never even see the file, and if they do get their hands on it, probably wouldn't know what to do with it.

Here is a nice tutorial on how to set up and connect to a simple derby database.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheDerby/article.html

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a Serializable interface that can be used to save java objects.

API docs can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

This doesn't make it impossible for people to cheat and change the maps just more difficult.

If you're really worried about it you could use some form of encryption or add a checksum to further prevent tampering.

Comment: Thank you! But i heard that serialization can cause trouble when updating/changing something inside the program.  I will take a closer look at it and see if it can be of use in this game!

Comment: That is very true. However if you want to mitigate issues use an enumeration to save via the serializer instead of the objects themselves. That way when you change the code you are adjusting that the enumerations mapping only.
Basically you have Map<Location<>,TileEnum> that you save and use a switch case or some other construct to relate the TileEnum to the tiles you want to use in the game. 
Note this will not work if you are trying to save game state and the tiles have a state they can be in.